# COBOL Internal SORT Error

Tags: sorting, cobol

I am facing an issue while sorting a sequential file using internal sort (with using and giving). The input file has a corrupt record so, the output file generated after sort is not complete.

It stops after encountering the corrupt record. However, the sort does not fail in the process. When I check the SORT-STATUS after this, it is coming zero. This causes the incomplete file to get processed further, which I do not want.

Is there a way to identify that there was a corrupt record in the process and the processing is incomplete so that I can end the program execution there only and correct the file before executing again?

Below is the code snippet:

```
SORT WRK-FILE
         ON ASCENDING KEY KEY1
                          KEY2
         USING INPUT-FILE
         GIVING OUTPUT-FILE.
IF SORT-STATUS = ZEROS 
   SET PROCESS-OK to TRUE
ELSE
   SET PROCESS-NOT-OK to TRUE
END-IF.
```

Comment: what compiler are you using? I was just looking at the IBM docs for SORT (because I don't know which version of COBOL you are using) and it references SORT-RETURN as a special register, but nothing about sort status. What is sort status in this context? Also, edit your question to make that code snippet a code block in the editor

Comment: Is this a Micro Focus compiler? Micro Focus has a `SORT STATUS`, similar to `FILE STATUS`. I have never used it, but it appears the value is usable only after `RELEASE` and `RETURN` statements.

Comment: As this is a file based sort you should be able to check the file's status field.

Comment: I did limited testing with Micro Focus and found that both the input and sort status reported "35" when the file was not present. Sort status reported "9/18" for a wrong-length record, but not for the input file and no output file was produced. It sorted numeric fields with alphanumeric data with no error reported and without stopping. I would like to know more about the "corrupted record".

Comment: @RickSmith Yes, it is a Micro Focus compiler. We're using Fujitsu cobol V7.0. So, you mean in USING-GIVING sort statement, SORT-STATUS doesn't work?

Comment: @SaggingRufus I am using a Micro Focus compiler and Fujitsu cobol V7.0. SORT-STATUS is similar to SORT-RETURN, it is just Micro Focus specific

Comment: The limited testing that I did suggests that it provides the status for the sort file(s) that it uses. So it appears to work with both `USING` and `GIVING` phrases as well as `RELEASE` and `RETURN` statements.